# Power pin used as power in and power out

Tags: power, spdt

This is my first post here... I hope I will do everything correctly.

I need to use a pin as power in and power out, switching it when needed. In particular, I want to use a USB micro B (5 pin) and use the ID pin as power in-out selector like an OTG cable does.

I need a power out when the ID is floating (NC) and power in when ID is connected to ground.

It can be done with an SPDT relay, but I don't have enough space to place it! So I need to realize the SPDT circuit over the main pcb.

[image]

To be more clear, I'm using the USB connector as a hardware connection only! No D+ or D-communications. It's useful that the battery charger will always be connected and the boost will power the load only when ID is tied to ground.

Specs:

- Voltage: 5V
- Current: 1A

Comment: There are special IC's for that.

Comment: So answer with the type of IC...

Comment: How much space do you have?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem. The circuit you are looking for comes under several names,

1. "OTG switch", like the [FPF3042](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FPF3042-D.pdf)
2. "load switch", an example is [FPF34892](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FPF34892-D.pdf)
3. As a last resort, use a "solid-state relay", example [LBA710](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/205/LBA710-311724.pdf).

There are ICs that provide all three functions shown in your diagram, as the crazy-complicated [LTC3576](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/lt-journal-article/LTMag-V19N2-03-LTC3576-GeorgeBarbehenn.pdf). I am sure Texas Instruments offers similar set of ICs. And many others.

So, possibilities are nearly unlimited.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Thanks Ali!! I think I will never use the LTC3576!! What do you mean for "all three functions"? I already have the boost IC and the battery charger, I only need the load switcher so the relay seems a good alternative...a bit expensive but good! How to realize the same relay with single components?